# javascript/redux: how to avoid null when fetching state?

Tags: javascript, redux

say I have a reducer like this:

```
export const fetchStuff = (state, action) => {
    const s = state || someDefaultState
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_STUFF:
            return {...s, isFetching: true} 
        case SET_STUFF:
            return {...s, isFetching: false, stuff: action.values}
        default:
            return s
    }
}
```

In this case if `actions.values` has objects that are `null` they will be very hard to deal with in my components because I will manually have to ensure that the component is not passed a null prop and then also manually have to deal with null fields in the component somewhere.

```
const component = ({ prop }) => {
    return {
        <div>
          <span>{prop.testnull ? '' : prop.testnull}</span>
        <div
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const p = prop || someDefaultProp
    return {
        prop: state.prop
    }
}
```

It might seem easy enough in this example, but I have found it a pain to manage  a bigger component/component-set. What is the idiomatic way of doing this? DO I have to bite the bullet and manage it in the component and `mapStateToProps`? or is there a better way to manage it in the reducer?

EDIT:

I should clarify that I am not trying to take care of the case where `state` is `null` I am trying to take care of the case where , on fetching of state, some attribute if state is set to null

Comment: const s = state || someDefaultState
You haven't use const s instead use state which can be null

Comment: that is a (now fixed) typo in my example, but the question still stands even if it is correct...

Comment: You can define a default value for `stuff`, and instead of passing null to `action.values`, check if it is null before setting it to a default value. Ex: `return {...s, isFetching: false, stuff: action.values ? action.values : []}`

Answer (score 2):

We have worked with a few similar solutions for a while, and found this to be a nice way of handling this use case in our reducers. Lodash's `_.get` is a nice solution to provide a default value for multi-level get in your reducer:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get

> #### `_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])`
>
> - `object` *`(Object)`*: The object to query.
> - `path` *`(Array|string)`*: The path of the property to get.
> - `[defaultValue]` *`(*)`*: The value returned for `undefined` resolved values.

For example:

```js
const testValue = get(action, 'values.test', {});
```